# Datagrid Cell content is not visible in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid with 8 columns,concatenating the first 2 column values and bind it to the 7th column for every rows.[binding process is done in calendar closed event of the 6th column]In this after binding the 7th column value the bonded value is not visible in the 7 cell of the particular row but if i double clicked on the particular cell then the data is visible...I don't know what is going wrong...

[image: This is the image of my Datagrid]

```
public class pojo
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int QuarterNo { get; set; }
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string PeriodName { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<pojo> models = new ObservableCollection<pojo>();

private void Period_Name(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var rowdata = calendarmstrDG.SelectedItem as pojo;
    var prefix = rowdata.Prefix;
    int year = rowdata.Year;
    int year_twodigits = year % 100;
    string sth = prefix + '-' + year_twodigits.ToString();
    pojo obj = (pojo)calendarmstrDG.SelectedItem;
    obj.PeriodName = sth;
}
```

Xaml code for 8th column

```xml
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PeriodName}"  Width="85" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Period Name"/>
```

Comment: You need to use INotifyOfPropertyChanged to get these result on UI immediately after setting

Comment: @sTrenat I guess `INotifyPropertyChanged` :)

Comment: Just search for this, even on StackOverflow there are hundreds answer how to implement this interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class should look like this (other fields are omitted):

```
public class pojo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _prefix;
    private int _year;

    public string Prefix
    {
        get => _prefix;
        set
        {
            if (_prefix == value) return;
            _prefix = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PeriodName));
        }
    }
    public int Year
    {
        get => _year;
        set
        {
            if (_year == value) return;
            _year = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PeriodName));
        }
    }
    public string PeriodName => _prefix + '-' + (_year % 100).ToString(); 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you made notify on wrong properties :P should be on PeriodName, instead of Year and Period

Comment: @sTrenat Nope, mate! `PeriodName` is bound to two these fields. Actually, OP has to have `MultipleBinding` (OP didn't include his XAML). :)

Comment: He's using normal Binding and concate it in code behind. What's more, with mulitBinding Notify is set by Ui, so he wouldn't need any in Code Behind :P

Comment: @sTrenat This is what I meant about Multibinding :) Sorry for misunderstanding :(

Comment: I mean, if something is set by xaml side, there is no need for INotify interface, so: 1.Use multibinding or 2.Use notify on PeriodName :P

Comment: @sTrenat Yes, that's why I mentioned Multibing. I guess this is simpler approach :)

Comment: But yeah, if he gonna change year or name, your solution is good, but at least tell him how to write Multibinding for his sample :P